# Count of users who are logged in per day

Tags: 7, views

I searched to find a way to display the number of users who are logged in per day.

I want to display a chart using views for last month to show the login statistics of the website.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Well in other to achieve this, you will be using a combination of modules.

Use the [counter](https://drupal.org/project/counter) module for gathering that kind of statistics. Another option is to enable the statistics module in Drupal core

> Counter module counts how many visitors on your website. This module
>   provides real time counting. All data saved to database.

And with [google chart tools](https://drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools) and the views module create a chart

> Display live data on your site using Google Chart Tools Google Chart
>   Tools module provides a simple API to Build custom interactive SVG
>   charts. The module contain an example module which demonstrate how
>   this module can be use.

Comment: How can i use counter module's statistics in views module?

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use Google Analytics and create a custom report in Google Analytics rather than your site?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It suggests and completely different approach than the OP is after, and provides absolutely no information on how to achieve the different approach.

Comment: it's not the solution that i'm looking for, thank you :D